# Sending an Integer as json using Restkit

Tags: ios, json, parsing, rest, restkit

Right now I'm working with Restkit to make REST and RPC request to a remote server from the iPhone device, it's a pretty awesome library.

Right now I got stuck with a simple problem. My server expects some data as integer. That means a json array that looks like this.

```
{'myInteger':1234}
```

Please notice that the value for my_integer_field key is not between ''. That means that the value is a number and not a string.

When I make the mappings and all the stuff I set my_integer_field as a NSNumber value in the object definition. But when the object is parsed to Json the value appears between '' like:

```
{'myInteger':'1234'}
```

So I get an error as response from the server because is asuming that '1234' represents a String and not a number. Is there a way to force the json parsing to not include '' on NSNumber fields?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code:

```
//myclass.h

@interface myClass : NSObject {

    NSNumber *myInteger;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *myInteger;

//appDelegate.m here is where i define the mappings for everything.

//myClass MAPPING

RKObjectMapping* myClassMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[myClass class]];
[myClassMapping mapAttributes:@"myInteger", nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:myClassMapping];

// myClass SERIALIZATION

RKObjectMapping* myClassSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[myClassSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"myInteger", nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:myClassSerializationMapping forClass:[myClass class]];
```

I'm missing something?

Comment: What ever ( I said whatever) you try to map into JSON, converts into string ! You have to manage with explicit casting while fetching it !

Comment: So... it's not posible to do what I want?

Comment: Its possible !! But when you use json data, try to type cast and then use it ! Got my point ?

Comment: Yeah, but that's on the server side... The ideal case will be the client sending the desired json instead of the server parsing it.

Comment: You mean your JSON is sent from client right ? Hey hey do me a fever ! What exception did you get actually ? Can you ?

Comment: Can you post your code for your mapping? SBJson, which restkit uses, converts NSNumbers to numbers in the json string, so it should look like your top example rather than your bottom.

Comment: I just updated the question, adding the code I'm using (simplified)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not precisely sure why you get this behavior, but have you tried just using:

`RKObjectMapping* myClassSerializationMapping = [myClassMapping inverseMapping];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:myClassSerializationMapping forClass:[myClass class]];`

Although I believe that RestKit uses inverseMapping by default if no serializationMapping is specified, so you might be able to just leave off that part entirely.